# Static Directories management in appengine Modules using dispatch.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml, python-module

I am currently using modules, a relatively new concept in appengine for subdomain routing.
It all works fine,except that static resources like stylesheets and images only seem to load at the "default" module and not the "admin" module i am using.

The default module's yaml file , app.yaml is:-

```
    application: check4se
    version: v1
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true

    automatic_scaling:
     max_idle_instances: 20

    handlers:


   - url: /stylesheets
     static_dir: stylesheets
     expiration: "1s"

   - url: /images
     static_dir: images
     expiration: "1s"

   - url: /js
     static_dir: js


   - url: .*
     script: Main2.app

    libraries:
     - name: jinja2
     version: latest
```

My admin.yaml for the module admin is as follows:-

```
     application: check4se
     module: admin
     version: v1
     runtime: python27
     api_version: 1
     threadsafe: false

     automatic_scaling:
     min_idle_instances: 2

     handlers:

     - url: .*
       script: admin.app


     - url: /_ah/login_required
       script: do_openid_login.py
```

I am using dispatch.yaml to route all static resources to my default module:-

```
      application: check4se

      dispatch:


      - url: "admin.check4se.appspot.com/*"
        module: admin

      - url: "*/images"
        module: default

      - url: "*/stylesheets"
        module: default

      - url: "*/js"
        module: default
```

What's the issue and workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the .* handler in the admin.yaml is matching the /_ah/login_required path, so the /_ah/login_required path never matches and never calls do_openid_login.py.

Instead, put the /_ah/login_required handler before the .* handler.

```
 application: check4se
 module: admin
 version: v1
 runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: false

 automatic_scaling:
 min_idle_instances: 2

 handlers:

 - url: /_ah/login_required
   script: do_openid_login.py

 - url: .*
   script: admin.app
```

Additionally, you might be having a similar problem with the dispatch.yaml

You may want to put the static resource paths first or else anything on the admin domain will go to the admin resource and no the default resource.

```
  application: check4se

  dispatch:

  - url: "*/images"
    module: default

  - url: "*/stylesheets"
    module: default

  - url: "*/js"
    module: default

  - url: "admin.check4se.appspot.com/*"
    module: admin
```

Comment: Sorry,had found the solution,forgot to close the question.Thanks for the answer,it was exactly what i did.